# Pivot Table Error ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have used pivot table in ArcToolbox of ArcGIS, while I did it, this of my result of summary table, the field is text format, but however it is has numeric value (year value), after using pivot, the value is not shown as it should be, here is my screen shot:

[image: Summary table)] [image: Pivot table result]

I guess the ArcGIS can't using field with numeric name?, why is this happen?, is this a bug?, `Thn_Buat_u` is in string format, but why it was changed in pivot result?

Comment: There is a restriction in databases that fields can't have numeric names, or at least not start with a number or underscore but this is dependent on the database type. Allthough you see numbers the field Thn_Buat_u *must* be text as it contains multiple values and commas. Can you explain more about what you're expecting from this pivot table? Perhaps it would be better to do this in Excel or similar due to fuzzy types in spreadsheets.

Comment: Yes, i've done this in Excel too, yet i need this in model builder, to automation my work. unfortunately this restriction is limit the automation it self, so the problem is solve when firstly i edit the column by field calculator.
I just wondering about what are other restriction in ArcGIS field,  such as underscore, or number?
and also, why the pivot field is supposed to named with number, and why is this field is automatically change with the previous field in Arcgis? 
see, when it is ", " is change to "__" and also the field supposed to named with "2004" and change to "thn_buat_u" and soon.